# 'tuple' object has no attribute 'page_content' when using KeyLLM with Langchain

Tags: python, langchain, large-language-model

I've been looking at creating a model to extract keywords using LLMs and found KeyBert and KeyLLM. I've been trying to combine this with langchain using the little tutorial in the docs but keep getting the error 'tuple' object has no attribute 'page_content' The code being used is:

```
import openai
from keybert.llm import OpenAI
from keybert import KeyLLM

# Create your LLM
openai.api_key = "sk-..."
llm = OpenAI()

# Load it in KeyLLM
kw_model = KeyLLM(llm)

# Extract keywords
document = "The website mentions that it only takes a couple of days to deliver but I still have not received mine."
keywords = kw_model.extract_keywords(document)
```

This produces the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-bad26e9f5d36> in <cell line: 12>()
     10 # Extract keywords
     11 text = "The website mentions that it only takes a couple of days to deliver but I still have not received mine."
---> 12 keywords = kw_model.extract_keywords(text)

9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/langchain/schema/prompt_template.py in format_document(doc, prompt)
    204             >>> "Page 1: This is a joke"
    205     """
--> 206     base_info = {"page_content": doc.page_content, **doc.metadata}
    207     missing_metadata = set(prompt.input_variables).difference(base_info)
    208     if len(missing_metadata) > 0:

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'page_content'
```

I have tried converting the string to a document using

```
docs = [Document(page_content=text)]

keywords = kw_model.extract_keywords(docs)
```

but this just produces the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-a05aabccae1b> in <cell line: 12>()
     10 # Extract keywords
     11 text = "The website mentions that it only takes a couple of days to deliver but I still have not received mine."
---> 12 keywords = kw_model.extract_keywords(docs)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keybert/llm/_langchain.py in extract_keywords(self, documents, candidate_keywords)
     94 
     95         for document, candidates in tqdm(zip(documents, candidate_keywords), disable=not self.verbose):
---> 96             prompt = self.prompt.replace("[DOCUMENT]", document)
     97             if candidates is not None:
     98                 prompt = prompt.replace("[CANDIDATES]", ", ".join(candidates))

TypeError: replace() argument 2 must be str, not Document
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback of the error.

Comment: I've added the full traceback of both errors produced

Comment: In the examples at https://maartengr.github.io/KeyBERT/guides/keyllm.html `documents` is just a list of strings. Have you tried that?

Comment: add more details, entire code sample what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Using a list of strings seems to give the same error

Comment: Right now this is the whole code sample, it's just using the snippet from the keybert documentation that I've been trying to get to work